# Utilizar o InnerJoin com o Limit

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-2

Tenho a tabela `A` com uma relação `OneToMany` com a tabela `B`.

A tabela `A` é pequena, possui 10 registros.

A tabela `B` possui N registros por cada registro na tabela `A`.

De X em X minutos é executado um script que exporta os 50 novos registros da tabela `B` (para cada registro na tabela `A`) para um ficheiro `txt`, por exemplo: a tabela `A` tem 10 registros, então o sistema procura na tabela `B` os 50 novos registros para cada registro na tabela `A`, nesse caso será 10x50, logo será exportado para o ficheiro `txt` 500 registros.

Para isso fiz um `innerjoin` no repositório:

```
class AppsRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function findNewClients()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
        $qb
            ->innerJoin('AppBundle\Entity\Clients', 'b', 'WITH', 'b.appId = a.id')
            ->where('b.proccessed is null')
    ;

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

Preciso limitar o `innerjoin` para retornar apenas 50 registros para cada registro na tabela `A` conforme expliquei acima.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
class AppsRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findNewClients()
    {
        return $this
            ->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('
                SELECT AppBundle:Apps a
                JOIN a.clients c
                WHERE c.processed IS NULL')
            ->setMaxResults(50)
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

E se você usar um LEFT JOIN ou RIGHT JOIN?

Algo parecido com isso:

SELECT t1.coluna1, t2.coluna1
FROM tabela1 AS t1 LEFT JOIN tabela2 AS t2
ON t1.coluna1 = t2.coluna1
LIMIT 50